# How to remove unwanted "extra line breaks" that appear in PHP/CSS/JS files after unzip?

Tags: unzip

Consider the following:

- Zip up a folder, upload to server
- unzip on server using 'unzip archive.zip'
- Download any PHP file from that folder
- Extra line breaks appear where unwanted

Any ideas why this happens or how to "undo it"?
I have tried to do a "find and replace" but that ends up basically minifying the entire file onto "1 line", which is not wanted either...

Examine the attached image here
[image]

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of posterity: I found that I was able to use this tactic:
https://pixelflips.com/blog/removing-line-breaks-in-dreamweaver

- Open the Find/Replace box (CMD+F / CTRL+F)
- In the Find enter: [\r\n]{2,}
- In the Replace enter: \n
- Check the box "Use regular expression" and un-check any other boxes.
- The hit "Replace All"

By using Adobe Dreamweaver, which works...

However, *I am not going to make my own answer correct* as I still wonder why this happens and want to prevent it if possible.